# Should I use heading tags in my navigation menus

Tags: html, css, seo, web-standards

Ive always wondered about this.  I like to create super navigation menus.  The website I am currently working on for example has a blog tab at the top, which has a drop down with latest blog posts and some other stuff.

Should I use heading tags for Semantics and SEO?

Here is my current structure:

```
<li class="submenu supermenu" id="blogmenu">
    <a href="/blog/">Blog</a>
    <ul>
        <li>                    
            <h4>Recent Posts</h4>
            <ul id="recentposts">
                <li>
                    <h5><a href="/blog/some-blog">Some blog title</a></h5>
                    <p>Snippet of blog post here...</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h5><a href="/blog/some-blog">Some blog title</a></h5>
                    <p>Snippet of blog post here...</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a id="bloglink" href="/blog/">View the full Blog</a></li>  
    </ul>
</li>
```

What do you guys think?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, I do it all the time. It *is* a heading, so the semantic equivalent in HTML is one of the `hn` elements - `h4` is a good choice here, assuming `h1`, `h2`, and `h3` are used for more *important* heading in your page.

Comment: my main fear is having a heading valued item repeated across every page, google may not like this repeated content from an seo perspective.

Comment: @Roeland SEO *shudder*. I'd rather be semantically correct than have a mix pile of tags for SEO purposes. YMMV.

Comment: @Alex, can you offer any sources / data points that support this?